# tableView viewForHeaderInSection starts with section 1 in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

{

    NSString *sectionTitle = @"";

    if(section == 0)
        sectionTitle = @"Overall Progress";
    else
        sectionTitle = [[courses objectAtIndex:section-1] objectForKey:@"course-name"];

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        label.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 300, 30);
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    }
    else
    {
        label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 20, 600, 60);
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19];

    }

    label.text = sectionTitle;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [label sizeToFit];
    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    }
    else{
        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 500)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [view addSubview:label];
    [view autorelease];
    return view;
}
```

Here in this code section returns 1 when I debug and hence the section 0 code doesn't get executed. Thus I am not able to get Overall Progress text in my table header view.

Comment: Whereas it is working fine in iOS 6 and below

Comment: what kind of error you face ?

Comment: I am not facing any kind of error. Its like it is not starting with section 0 and so my section 0 code is not getting executed....

Comment: pls post your other delegates methods also

Comment: How many rows does section 0 have?

Comment: Just `NSLog(@"section: %d", section);` in this method and check.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to implement heightForHeaderInSection with the height that you want.

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 44;
    }
```

from tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:

> Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual height for each section header in this method.

from tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:

> The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view. This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

see [UITableViewDelegate protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)

Answer (score 0):

What is in the implementation of tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:? If you return 0 there for section 0, then our view will be resized to be not visible at all.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    return 27.0;
}